# Scripting Assistance for Management CLI in JBoss

Tags: jboss, command-line-interface, jboss7.x

I am somewhat new to JBoss. I like handling things from the terminal itself but I don't know all the commands or not yet clear how to write the commands myself. Is there any way to generate CLI scripts for Jboss from the actions done in console. Similar to command assistance tool in WebSphere. Or is there any book or site that provides all the management cli commands.

I tried looking it up on the Internet but all I could find was command history. But that is usefull for remembering what command you have executed previously. I want to know the commands for actions I am performing in console.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but CLI does have tab completion.

Comment: how do I access or enable this tab completion

Comment: It’s enabled by default when you’re using the interactive client.